# How to integrate zxing Barcode Scanner library into my Android application?

Tags: android, zxing

I am new to android development.I need to integrate barcode reader in my android application.
i searched the net and i found Zxing library.

I am trying to use this library in my project when running i got the follwoing error in my logcat.

```
03-28 16:29:27.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29626): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-202
03-28 16:29:27.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29626): Process: com.agn.barcodereader, PID: 29626
03-28 16:29:27.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29626): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.setHints
03-28 16:29:27.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29626):    at jim.h.common.android.zxinglib.DecodeHandler.<init>(DecodeHandler.java:46)
03-28 16:29:27.808: E/AndroidRuntime(29626):    at jim.h.common.android.zxinglib.DecodeThread.run(DecodeThread.java:96)
```

This is my call

```
IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MainActivity.this, 
                    R.layout.capture,R.id.viewfinder_view, 
                    R.id.preview_view, true);
```

and i have included all the required jars.

and i created capture.xml file under my layout folder.

Could anybody help me to solve this problem.

thanks in advance

Regards,
John.

Comment: Check this http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Comment: Why not use a intent to ask user what barcode scanner use?

Comment: It looks like he/she is using Intents, but, this is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Just Follow this Link.
https://code.google.com/p/android-zxinglib/

At Left side you will find a zip file named "ZxingjarDemo.zip"
Just Download it and implement it in your application.

Comment: +1, works like a charm! Can't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to integrate by `Intent`. However your error comes from code that you do not need and should not have in your app if so, like `DecodeThread`. Remove whatever that is, and instead call `IntentIntegrator` as you show, and also implement the callback as shown in the javadoc. Code like `DecodeThread` is irrelevant to `Intent`s.